# Resetting setInterval with an onclick button

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I'm trying to modify a script and reset a setInterval with an onclick button. 
What I would like to do is clear the Interval and start from the beginning (status 1), but I have trouble to know how..

```
        var face = 0;
        var t = 100;
        var status = 0;
        var tInt = 100;

        (function () {
            var element = document.getElementById("header");
            element.style.top = (window.innerHeight/2 - element.clientHeight/2) + "px";

            intro.play();

            var analysis = setInterval(function() {
                    if (status > 0) {
                    t = face ? t + tInt : 0;

                    var element = document.getElementById("header");

                    if (status == 1) {
                        element.innerHTML = '<p class="spectrum title">MONTREZ VOTRE VISAGE</p>';
                        element.style.top = (window.innerHeight/2 - element.clientHeight/2) + "px";
                        intro.stop();
                        scan.stop();
                        wait.play();
                        status = 2;
                    } else if (status == 2 && t > 0 && t < 5000) {
                        element.innerHTML = '<p class="spectrum">Analyse en cours</p><p class="spectrum">PATIENTEZ...</p>';
                        element.style.top = (window.innerHeight - element.clientHeight - 48) + "px";
                        wait.stop();
                        scan.play();
                        status = 3;
                    } else if (status == 3 && t >= 5000) {
                        element.innerHTML = '<p class="perdu">DÉSOLÉ</p><p class="perdu title">Votre visage n\'est pas conforme!</p>';
                        element.style.top = (window.innerHeight - element.clientHeight - 48) + "px";
                        scan.stop();
                        theme.play();
                        status = 4;
                        clearInterval(analysis);
                    } else if (status == 3 && t == 0) {
                        status = 1;
                    }
                }
            }, tInt);
```

Comment: You already appear to be clearing the interval - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, the interval is cleared when status is 3 and after 5000 ms. What I want is to start over. A button that start from status 1

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an click event to a button, and resetting the action and t values inside the click event

html

```
<button id="btnReset" onclick="resetValue();">Reset</button>
```

add this extra function to the javascript

```
function resetValue() {
    action = 1;
    t = 0;
    // stop started items
    intro.stop();
    wait.stop();
    scan.stop();
    theme.stop();
    // clear elements
    var element = document.getElementById("header");
    if (element) {
        element.innerHTML = '';
        element.style.top = (window.innerHeight/2 - element.clientHeight/2) + "px";
    }
    // restart intro
    intro.play();
};
```

this should reset to the start, while continueing the interval loop

added a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/GaQEp/ that shows this with start/stop/reset buttons, and some mokked functionalities. Did partly rebuild your script though :)

Comment: It's kind of working my problem is that only partial of the interval is starting over, but the loop is not working.

Comment: I updated my answer to reset the elements and possible "playing" items

Comment: Thanks for all of this, the clearing is okay but sadly it doesn't start again. I guess I want to do something too complicated for me...

What I wanted to do initially is to start the scan frame and the messages to start over. This is a jsfiddle that shows the code: http://jsfiddle.net/KevoMercure/qkFrD/14/

I put your function into it also.

Comment: Did you check my fiddle? I rebuild your given functionality in there. If you have problems reintegrating the changes, please ask ;)

Comment: When I integrate your code, the buttons and the messages are okay, but I can't get them work with the camera and the drawtocanvas functions... I'm getting lost here